# Loop in csv file

Tags: java, loops, csv

I asked this question before however I did not get the answer that I expected. Therefore I opened this new question.

My try:

```
    String fileName = "placements.csv";
        try {
          // Assume default encoding.
          FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

          // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
          BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
          // First row, write the head of the csv file.
          bufferedWriter.write(FILE_HEADER);
          bufferedWriter.newLine();
          // Increase the begin date 1 seconds until test end date.
          int seconds = 0;
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime(beginDate);
          for (int j = 0; j < convertedDifference; j++) {
            for (Job currentJob : NEHCalculator.sequenceOrderListofJobs()) {

              int times = (int) ((convertedDifference / currentJob.getInterval()) * testDevices());

              for (int i = 0; i < currentJob.getNeededTestTime() * times; i++) {

                cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
                beginDate.getTime();
                // write the test date
                bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(cal.getTime()));
                bufferedWriter.write(";");
                bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(seconds));
                bufferedWriter.write(";");
                bufferedWriter.write(currentJob.getJobname());
                bufferedWriter.write(";");
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
              }// end of currentjob loop
              seconds++;
            }// end first for loop
          }
          bufferedWriter.close();// Always close files.

        } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + fileName);
        }  
}
```

First for loop `for (int j = 0; j < convertedDifference; j++)` : I restrict my program until test end date. If I enter 1 hour test time, i expected to see number 0 until 3599 seconds.

Second for loop `for (Job currentJob : NEHCalculator.sequenceOrderListofJobs())`: I want to test every devices in the list.

For third for loop `for (int i = 0; i < currentJob.getNeededTestTime() * times; i++)`: I expected to test first job `currentJob.getNeededTestTime() * times times`.

For example I have 1 hour test time and interval of fist job is 15 min and it tests 2 devices and test needed time 2 seconds. So the output must be:

```
Mon Feb 22 12:59:59 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:00 CET 2016;1;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:01 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:02 CET 2016;3;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:03 CET 2016;4;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:04 CET 2016;5;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:05 CET 2016;6;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:06 CET 2016;7;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:07 CET 2016;8;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:08 CET 2016;9;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:09 CET 2016;10;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:10 CET 2016;11;WAF5-H; 
Mon Feb 22 13:00:11 CET 2016;12;WAF5-H; 
Mon Feb 22 13:00:12 CET 2016;13;WAF5-H; 
Mon Feb 22 13:00:13 CET 2016;14;WAF5-H; 
Mon Feb 22 13:00:14 CET 2016;15;WAF5-H; then it will continue with second job until end of the job list.
```

However the output of my code is:

```
Mon Feb 22 12:59:59 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:00 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:01 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:02 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:03 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:04 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:05 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:06 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:07 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H;
Mon Feb 22 13:00:08 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H; until Mon Feb 22 17:55:08 CET 2016;7082;WAF5-H;
```

It is completely wrong and I spend really so soo much time but I failed with this task. Could someone please help me.

Best regards,

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a better question. Or ask a question at all. It is not clear what the problem is or what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the code above is my code and first output is the expected one and second output is the actual output that is generated by me. The aim is achieved expected output. The problem: why the second column is written same number many time and the loop did not work with the second job.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing this code

`bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(seconds));`

for this one:

`bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)));`

I think it might work

Comment: with this changing, the variable seconds is written true.I created a test case until 1 hour testing but the program is written until Mon Feb 22 18:28:36 CET 2016;17969;WAF5-H;  The seconds variable is written until 17969. however the convertedDifference is 3600 seconds.

Comment: What do you expect for the third column?

Comment: Second column ( not third) gives information about seconds and when I make 1 hour testing I would expected to see result 0 until 3599. But it writes down result until 17969. Somehow the for (int j = 0; j < convertedDifference; j++) does not work. I entered 3600 seconds for the variable convertedDifference.

Comment: You're right, it's not third column but the second. But if you want to get the seconds you're doing it wrong because your variable `seconds` it's an integer that you're incrementing in the loop, so the result of that variable will be the number of interactions in the loop. What about changing it to `beginDate.getSeconds();`?

Comment: The method getSeconds() from the type Date is deprecated. I think it is not up-to-date method.

Comment: Changed the answer, hope it can help you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104277/discussion-between-limonik-and-tumisma).